# The anaconda-navigator stops working after installing gdal

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, gdal

I am new to python and anaconda
I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.5

After installing gdal with the command (in the Anaconda prompt)

`>conda install -c conda-forge gdal`

the anaconda-navigator does not launch anymore and I get the error message:

`pythonw: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "".`

I think it is because some packages were downgraded...  during the installation I got the message:

`The following packages will be DOWNGRADED due to dependency conflicts:`

```
anaconda-navigator: 1.3.1-py35_0                       --> 1.2.3-py35_0
matplotlib:         1.5.3-np111py35_0                  --> 1.5.1-np111py35_0
```

what is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions to this problem, I think the second one is better:

Solution 1: I first solved this problem by using python 2.7 instead of 3.5.

In fact with the command:
`>conda install gdal`

I got the following message:

`UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - gdal
  - python 3.5*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.`

So I created a new environment with python 2.7, following the instructions [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html)

`>conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda`
`activate py27`
Then I installed the gdal (and other packages I needed)
`>conda install gdal`

It is then possible to directly launch the anaconda-navigator (just typing `anaconda-navigator` in the command line. Also opening the anaconda-navigator from the menu I can select the environment with "application on: py27" and start spyder in this environment.

Solution 2: I kept using python 3.5 but instead of using conda install I downloaded the compatible binaries from the ["Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages"](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

`>pip install <package-path>`